# jquery mobile - on select choice, update html results with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile's multiple select: custom to try and help filter data based on the user's selection(s).

I can see that jquery mobile already updates text ON SELECT because selecting an option automatically changes the text in the select menu.

Is there a way to tap into that, so that I can send the value of the selected options to a php page through AJAX and return results via JSON?

```
<form id="target" method="post">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="select-choice-attunement" class="select ui-hidden-accessible">Filter Attunement</label>
<select data-mini="true" name="select-choice-attunement" id="select-choice-attunement" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Filter by Element</option>
    <option value='1'>fire</option>
    <option value='2'>water</option>
    <option value='3'>earth</option>
    <option value='4'>light</option>
    <option value='5'>darkness</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

To make it a bit more clear.

From the list above, you can see there are only 5 choices.  The user might finish after 1, or all 5.  The results need to mirror what they chose, preferably as fast as possible (which is why I would like to hook to jquery mobiles update).   So if the choose 'fire' it will immediately filter via the called php function and returned json list, the necessary list items.

Lets imagine that I wanted to update the following with a new array of list items:

View:

```
<div id='change_with_ajax'>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($ajaxretrievedarray as $array) 
{
echo "<li>".$array['name']."</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the below example.

When the change event is triggered, the selected values are displayed inside an alert box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Select Choice</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).on('change', '#select-choice-attunement', function(e){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Select Choice</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="select-choice-attunement" class="select ui-hidden-accessible">Filter Attunement</label>
                    <select data-mini="true" name="select-choice-attunement" id="select-choice-attunement" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option>Filter by Element</option>
                        <option value='1'>fire</option>
                        <option value='2'>water</option>
                        <option value='3'>earth</option>
                        <option value='4'>light</option>
                        <option value='5'>darkness</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: aha. so simple. I should have figured jquery would allow me to use the name of the select. Thanks